# How to code a Sum Block when working with Transfer Functions?

Tags: signal-processing, control-systems

I am working using transfer functions models with Mathematica and i am missing a basic feature like the ability to use a Sum Block.

[image]

How could the model above be modeled?

Considering:

```
C = TransferFunctionModel[2];
P = TransferFunctionModel[1/(s + 2), s];
```

And noise being a generic signal like a sine wave or a constant noise.

Comment: Are you trying to run simulations in the time domain or in the frequency domain? I note that your transfer function is defined in the s plane. Are you after a simulation or a symbolic analysis?

Comment: I would like to run simulations in the time domain and do other tasks like transfer function shaping or stability studies in the Laplace Transform domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways a sum block could be specified.

Directly:

```
sum = TransferFunctionModel[{{1, 1}}]
```

> [image]

```
StateSpaceModel[{{}, {}, {}, {{1, 1}}}]
```

> [image]

```
AffineStateSpaceModel[{{}, {}, {}, {{1, 1}}}, {}, {u1, u2}]
```

> [image]

```
NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u1 + u2}, {}, {u1, u2}]
```

> [image]

Or from the equation:

```
StateSpaceModel[{y[t] == u1[t] + u2[t]}, {y[t]}, {u1[t], u2[t]}, {y[t]}, t]
```

> [image]

After that the complete system can be obtained using [`SystemsConnectionsModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsConnectionsModel.html) and [`SystemsModelMerge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelMerge.html):

```
c = TransferFunctionModel[2];
p = TransferFunctionModel[1/(s + 2), s];


SystemsConnectionsModel[{c, p, sum}, {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}, {2, 1} -> {3, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{3, 1}}];
SystemsModelMerge[%]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you, i have to say that, while it is really simple, it's not easy to find on the docs. Now it is pretty clear.